# Addin jquery-ui datepicker on HTMLDialogElement.showModal() (bypass pseudo backdrop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-datepicker

**Question**

An input element is in `<dialog>` tag of HTML and showModal is used to open the dialog as modal. Is there a way to open jquery-ui-datepicker on top of dialog. Right now, it is hiding behind the dialog

**Traditional asnwer**

The traditional answer was that to add z-index on datepicker but its not working due to ::backdrop pseduo-element.

**HTMLDialogElement.showModal blocks all other interactions**

By definition, the [`HTMLDialogElement.showModal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal) blocks all interaction except for the dialog.

> The showModal() method of the HTMLDialogElement interface displays the dialog as a modal, over the top of any other dialogs that might be present. It displays into the top layer, along with a ::backdrop pseudo-element. Interaction outside the dialog is blocked and the content outside it is rendered inert.

Is there a way to bring the datepicker on top?

**Possible trick**

Of-course we can use HTMLDialogElement.show() and it can solve the problem, but is there a way to force the picker to bring on top while using showModal().

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue and wrote a little workaround:

```
const datePickerContainer = $('.myDatePicker');
datePickerContainer.datepicker({...});

const dialogParent = datePickerContainer.parents('dialog');

if (dialogParent.length > 0) {
    const widget = datePickerContainer.datepicker( "widget" );
    widget.detach();
    dialogParent.append(widget);
}
```

I check if the target field is inside of a dialog and move the datepicker widget into it, after the datepicker is initialized.